# Can't use Ionic 3 + Material Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, ionic3

I can't make Ionic 3 + [Material angular](https://material.angular.io) work together.

I've followed every stepped, installing `angular/material`, `angular/cdk`, `angular/animation` and bring `BrowserAnimationsModule` to `app.module.ts`. I've imported `MatCardModule` from `'@angular/material'` and added it to `imports` array. And I finally tried to use it with `<mat-card>Simple card</mat-card>`.

> **Error:** Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: 'mat-card'
>   is not a known element:
>   1. If 'mat-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'mat-card' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>   ("
>       `

How can I make it work together?

Comment: This is an import problem. Check that you have importer it in the specific ts file you are in for example

Comment: I am pretty sure importing anything onto the component.ts files, only modules need imports I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add schema in module component and check again.

```
    @NgModule({
schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    })
```

Comment: Was you able to do this? From where should we import CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA?

Comment: import {NgModule,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,ErrorHandler} from '@angular/core';  add this. if you get some other exception let me know

Comment: do you really want to merge ionic and Angular material? Ionic was already designed for android with material design. I never tried to merge ionic and angular material, I just gave the answer for error message

Comment: Okay I was able to do this, the problem was I imported it in app.module.ts it seems this does not work, importing it in module where I also import material admin module does work.

Comment: At your question, do I really want that? That's a good question! The problem is Ionic is slow adding custom components, there are many PR's they doesn't care. So for example on a progress-bar someone has created a PR for it nearly one year ago. So this is my try to check if I can use some single componenets and on how my project will grow up using this.

Comment: Great try! Please let me know if it works so I can try in my project too 